# What is meant by profiling by some one?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

If some one is treating any other person with discrimination based on their apparent similarity with any religious or ethnic or gender group, can we call this action an act of profiling?

Answer (score 2):

'profiling' is the activity of collecting important and useful details about someone or something.

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/profiling)

What one does with the collected information, which may or may not include treating that person with discrimination, falls out of the purview of 'profiling'.